# How to use session in GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-luna

Im a beginner. Can i use session to track the person who are using the current application by displaying her id or name? if yes, can someone show me the code for example?

Answer (score 2):

`System.getProperty("user.name")` will return the username of the current user as a String.

Comment: i mean using gui. sorry.

Comment: @Mong2203 Ok, using GUI : `myLabel.setText(System.getProperty("user.name"));` The `myLabel` field is the `Label` Object from AWT.

Comment: Have you done any researches about that ? There is a lot of tutorials on the Internet to start with GUI. I will not write a GUI here sorry.

Comment: Hi @Mong2203 do we need to create that label in each jform class?